# Retrieving text file using Net::FTP without login

Tags: ruby, ftp

I'm just starting to learn Ruby, so one of my first projects is to develop a [METAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR) logger that writes into a MySQL database. However, I'm running into an issue getting the actual source string from the National Weather Service.

The National Weather Service/NOAA makes METAR reports available via a text file stored on an FTP server (i.e. [here](ftp://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/observations/metar/stations/KSFO.TXT)), so obviously using `Net::HTTP` is out of the question. The thing I can't figure out how to do, though, is how to access the FTP server (or, at least, obtain the file) without FTP credentials - it works perfectly fine credential-less from the above (direct URL) access.

I found [this link on the Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/143424) to someone who was coincidentally trying the same thing I was, and tried a stripped-down version of the code to see if I could get the hang of it, namely:

```
require 'net/ftp'

def getMETARData (id)
    ftp = Net::FTP.new ('tgftp.nws.noaa.gov')
    ftp.chdir ('/data/observations/metar/stations')
    metardata = ftp.gettextfile ("#{id.upcase}.TXT")
    ftp.close
    return metardata
end

puts getMETARData ("KSFO")
```

However, when I attempt to run with `$ ruby test.rb`, I get the following error:

```
test.rb:29: warning: assigned but unused variable - metardata
<...>/net/ftp.rb:327:in `getresp': 530 Please login with USER and PASS. (Net::FTPPermError)
```

Attempting to issue a blank login (`ftp.login`) and the FTP passive command after the `Net::FTP` instantiation does not work either. That gives a different error:

```
test.rb:31: warning: assigned but unused variable - metardata
<...>/net/ftp.rb:327:in `getresp': 550 Permission denied. (Net::FTPPermError)
```

Any ideas on how to alleviate this issue?

Also, in full disclosure,

- Yes, I did try using `Net:HTTP` to directly access the URL above, didn't put that possibility here because it was a shot in the dark
- I'm not using one of the already-available METAR retrieval and parsing libraries ([example](https://github.com/joeyates/metar-parser)) because I want to get the hang of working with strings and Ruby syntax in general.

---

**EDIT**

After following @infused's answer to log in anonymously, I placed `puts` on both `ftp.login` and `ftp.sendcmd`. The following is the string of errors that results when it is run:

```
true
227 Entering Passive Mode (140,90,101,79,6,131).
/Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:327:in `getresp': 550 Permission denied. (Net::FTPPermError)
from /Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:339:in `voidresp'
from /Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:362:in `block in voidcmd'
from /Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:360:in `voidcmd'
from /Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:376:in `sendport'
from /Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:387:in `makeport'
from /Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:422:in `transfercmd'
from /Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:518:in `block (2 levels) in retrlines'
from /Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:199:in `with_binary'
from /Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:516:in `block in retrlines'
from /Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:515:in `retrlines'
from /Users/blasthash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/ftp.rb:647:in `gettextfile'
from test.rb:30:in `getMETARData'
from test.rb:35:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login using the username "anonymous" and either "guest" or your email address as the password:

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new ('tgftp.nws.noaa.gov')
ftp.passive = true
ftp.login 'anonymous', 'guest'
ftp.chdir ('/data/observations/metar/stations')
...
```

You'll find more info about anonymous FTP [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1635).

Comment: Still throws a 550 my way, although I think I'm getting warmer. I did some poor man's tracing using `puts` on `ftp.login 'anonymous', 'guest'` as well as on `ftp.sendcmd ('PASV')` - it gives a `true` and then a `227`.

Comment: The specific error lists `getresp` as the point with a list of other entities culminating in `gettextfile` at `ftp.rb:647`. I'll edit the full error into the post.

Comment: I found the issue with this site.  You need to set the FTP connection mode to passive and then it works fine. I updated my answer with how to do so.

Comment: Is there a specific order the connection mode and login must be made in? Right below `ftp.login` I have `ftp.sendcmd ('PASV')`; the server confirms passive mode with a 227 but I'm still getting an apparent error on `gettextfile`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you do it before or after the login, but you must use `ftp.passive = true`.  `ftp.sendcmd ('PASV')` will not work correctly.

Comment: That time worked! I had to fiddle with the variable `metardata` somewhat, but I just achieved output. Thank you very much.